# Oracle SQL TO_DATE and TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have two queries in Oracle SQL that are equivalent.

```
SELECT ... FROM TABLE WHERE timestamp = TO_DATE('2017-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

and

```
SELECT ... FROM TABLE WHERE 
timestamp >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND
timestamp < TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Generally, I need to run this everyday (automated) so the first query will suffice for the application. However, for the first few runs I need some custom date-time boundaries, so I might manually intervene and use the second query instead.

What I observed is that the first one run faster. Under the hood, is this really the case? Is the performance difference significant enough? Can someone explain?

Comment: pl/sql is a procedural language (different from SQL) and it has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: The two queries are not equivalent. The first query may retrieve very few rows (perhaps none!) even when the second query may retrieve thousands of rows. Are you implying that **in your data** the timestamps always have the time portion equal to 00:00:00, and that makes the two queries equivalent? **You** may know that, but Oracle has no way of knowing it without reading the values, so it is not surprising that even then the first query will be faster than the second. Yes, under the hood it is really the case that the two queries are not the same.

Comment: Also, in the first query why are you comparing the timestamp to a date, and not to a timestamp? Then: to avoid an unnecessary function call, you can use the timestamp literal syntax: `... timestamp_column = (or >= etc.) timestamp '2017-07-01 00:00:00'`.

Comment: @mathguy Yes, timestamp column has a format of `2017-07-01 00:00:00.0`

Comment: @menorah84, no a timestamp column *has no format*. The question is, *what does the data contain*? Is the time set to exactly `00:00:00.000000` on all records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devil is in the details.

1) How many records in the table?

2) How many records satisfy

```
timestamp = TO_DATE('2017-07-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

3) How many records satisfy

```
timestamp >= TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-01 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND
timestamp < TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-07-02 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

4) Does the table have stats collected? Does the `timestamp` column has histogram statistics?

5) Do you have an index on the `timestamp` column? Or it might be (sub)partitioned by timestamp?

It might be easier just send DDLs for both table and index - it will be really helpful.

Assuming you have `timestamp` column indexed, for the first query you're looking up by one value, in another case it is a range of value. So depending on stats and many other factors some of which are mentioned above, Oracle can choose to switch to full table scan for example, if it thinks that the second predicate returns much more rows so that its less expensive to read table directly.

I know it might be more questions than answers, but Oracle Database is very flexible and with flexibility comes complexity. Hope some of the above information will be helpful.

Also, a simple explain plan, sqlplus autrotrace or best case a [10053 trace](https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/how-do-i-capture-a-10053-trace-for-a-sql-statement-called-in-a-plsql-package) or a 10046 trace can show a more definitive answere what's going on there.

Comment: They return the same number of rows.